# How to write multicast delegate in C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to call few button click events together on a single button click.
How do i write it? Can I use multicast delegate concept here?

My Scenario:

I have a button named XYZ. Upon clicking this , the event handler i have written for other buttons of my application must be called one by one.

Can anyone help me out in this?
I went through this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1077/Delegates-in-managed-C
but it doesnt work for me :(

Comment: Have a look at http://www.oneunified.net/blog/Personal/SoftwareDevelopment/Delegate.article

Comment: Try looking at my answer at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303327/multicast-delegates-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If you're *limited* to Microsoft Visual C++ you can use [`__event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb1dzt8t.aspx), it's very similar to [`event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s.aspx) in the managed world.

First declare the method you want to make an *event* prepending `__event` to the method:

```
__event void OnButtonClicked(...);
```

Then decorate the class that contains the method with:

```
[event_source(native)]
class MyEventGenerator
{
public:
    __event void OnButtonClicked(const void* pSender, const void* pArguments);
};
```

To raise the event you simply call the function (prepending the `__raise` keyword is optional but it'll make clear in the code you're raising an event). Note that you can even raise the event from outside the class because it's a simple method call.

The class you'll use to handle the event must be decorated with:

```
[event_receiver(native)]
class CMyEventReceiver
{
public:
    void OnButtonClicked(const void* pSender, const void* pArguments);
};
```

To attach an event you do not have the *sugar* of `+=` so you must write something like this inside the `CMyEventReceiver` class:

```
 __hook(&CMyEventGenerator::OnButtonClicked, pEventGenerator,
    &CMyEventReceiver::OnButtonClicked);
```

Note that to detach the event handler you have to use the `__unhook` keyword.

Comment: I tried doing this , but when I execute the application , on buttonclick I am facing an error which says "An invalid argument was encountered"

Comment: I also dint get the idea about the event source and event reciever class. In my scenario both reciever and source are the same class. Hope my query is clear .Sorry If i am confusing you

Comment: You can use both on the same class, if needed (I imagine you have the same class but different objects!!!).
If you really do not feel comfortable with it you may simply use a std::vector of member function pointers (if everything is inside the class...) or (if boost is an option) a std::vector of boost::function. If you have...time then read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible, it's very very very good (and its delegate implementation may fit your needs).