# Multicast delegates in C++

Tags: c#, c++

I am in the process of converting some C# code into C++. I had initially though of replacing the delegates with C-style callbacks. However, on further inspection of the code, I have realized that this is not going to work, as the delegates are being used in a multicast manner, with (pseudo C# code) statements like:

```
DelegateTypeOne one = new DelegateTypeOne(someCallbackFunc1)
one += new DelegateTypeOne(someCallbackFunc2)
```

I understand that if the code being ported used the delegates in a single cast fashion, then using regular C style function pointers may have worked. On that note, I have one question, is the following C++ code valid?:

```
typedef std::vector<int> (CallbackTypeOne*) (const std::string& s, const bool b);
std::vector<int> foo (const std::string& s, const bool b);

CallbackTypeOne func_ptr = NULL;

func_ptr =  new CallbackTypeOne(foo);  // Note: new being used on a typedef not a type

// or should I just assign the func the normal way?
func_ptr =  foo;   // this is what I am doing at the moment
```

My original idea on implementing delegates would be to write an ABC called Delegate, which would be a functor. All other delegates would derive from this ABC, and they will have a STL container (most likely, a list), which will contain a list of any assigned functions, to be called in a sequential order.

This seems to be rather a lot of work, and I'm not even convinced its the most suitable approach. Has anyone done this sort of C# to C++ traqnslation before, and what is the recommended way to implement multicast delegates in C++?

Comment: I would recommend checking out the Boost library (www.boost.org).  This can be a complicated task in c++.

Comment: Using `new` to allocate `CallBackTypeOne` is probably not what you intend to do and it doesn't yield valid C++ either. Just use `func_ptr = foo;`

Answer (score 5):

I have two possible solution proposals

1. Use a vector of function pointers, instead of a function pointer. Define a class that holds a vector of callbacks and has operator() that when invoked will invoke the callbacks
2. Use [boost signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/signals.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try this example of a Multicast delegate.  It assumes C++11 => gcc 4.7 or later.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//      Bind and Function
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;


class Greeting
{
public:
    Greeting(const string& name) : name(name) {}
    string Hello() { return "Hello " + name; }
    string Wait() { return "Wait " + name; }
    string Goodbye() { return "Goodbye " + name; }
private:
    string name;
};

template <typename T>
struct Delegate
{
    vector<T> list;

    void operator+=(T item)
    {
        list.push_back(item);
    }

    void operator() ()
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            T item;
            item = list[i];
            cout << item() << endl;
        }
    }
};


//////

int main()
{
    // create pointer to function objects
    function<string()> f;
    Delegate<function<string()>> d;
    Greeting john("John");
    Greeting sue("Sue");

    // load up multicast delegate
    d += bind(&Greeting::Hello, john);
    d += bind(&Greeting::Goodbye, sue);
    d += bind(&Greeting::Wait, john);

    // fire delegate
    d();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice example. btw, what is the purpose of function<string()> f; is this one needed at all?

Answer (score 0):

The most simplistic approach is to use e.g. `std::vector< std::function<TSignature> >` as the backing structure of a multicast delegate. However, even with `std::function` as a wrapper for any callable type, the details can get pretty awkward, therefore I'd too recommend using `boost::signals`...